# How to concat datatypes like integers(integer with integer) & varchar(varchar with varchar) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can we concat

1. integers with integers
2. varchar with varchar
3. int with varchar

in MySQL ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `CONCAT`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
SELECT CONCAT(1, 2);
-- "12"

SELECT CONCAT('foo', 'bar');
-- "foobar"

SELECT CONCAT(1, 'bar');
-- "1bar"
```

Comment: It is used for integers as well as for varchars ? because I was under the impression that CONCAT is used only for string types.

Comment: Yes, it converts the integers. You can find the details if you follow the link @nickf provided.

Comment: Mysql does not convert integer as strings as you would expect. It yanks the binary representation of the number, which is not the same.         "if the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid that, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:

SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);

Answer (score 45):

> if the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid that, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);
```

[5.1 Documentations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: update user set emailId= select CONCAT( 2000000000, userId,'@xyz.local'). What is wrong with this?

Answer (score -1):

For two columns concatenation
name: CHAR
and
no: int

PIG syntax is CONCAT(name,(CHARARRAY)no);