# CONCAT() result unexpectedly truncated when LEFT JOIN or GROUP BY is used in query

Tags: mysql, concatenation

A MySQL query containing a `CONCAT()` is truncating the result unexpectedly and returning only 5 of the anticipated 6 characters ('abcd2' instead of abcd21').
A trimmed down version of the actual query follows:

```
SELECT c.cid, c.club, c.crewno, CONCAT(c.club,c.crewno) crewcode
 FROM `crews` c
 LEFT JOIN `results` r ON r.rno=c.cid
 GROUP BY c.cid;
```

The above query returns:

```
54321, 'abcd', 21, 'abcd2'
65432, 'abcd', 1, 'abcd1'
```

However, if the `LEFT JOIN` is removed and/or if the `GROUP BY` is removed then the `CONCAT()` works as expected and returns:

```
54321, 'abcd', 21, 'abcd21'
65432, 'abcd', 1, 'abcd1'
```

I have no idea what the problem is...

Additional information: the field `c.club` has type `VARCHAR(4)` and the field `c.crewno` has type `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED`. The outcome is unaffected by whether or not the results table contains rows to join.

A temporary workaround is in place using `TRIM(CONCAT(c.club,c.crewno,' '))`, which returns the expected values:

```
54321, 'abcd', 21, 'abcd21'
65432, 'abcd', 1, 'abcd1'
```

However, rather than live with an ugly workaround, I'd prefer to learn what the underlying problem is and fix it properly!

Edit 1: if a three digit `crewno` is used then only the first digit is returned and to get all three using my workaround I need to add a double space `TRIM(CONCAT(c.club,c.crewno,'  '))`.

Edit 2: SQL for setting up tables to demonstrate the problem follows. This is not production SQL but the minimum set of fields required to replicate the issue. (Note: when the results table is completely empty the `CONCAT()` works as expected but as soon as it has data the `CONCAT` returns the unexpected results)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crewsmin` (
 `cid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `club` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `crewno` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1;
INSERT INTO `crewsmin` (`cid`, `club`, `crewno`) VALUES
 (12345, 'abcd', 0),
 (12346, 'bcde', 5),
 (12347, 'cdef', 13),
 (12348, 'defg', 42),
 (12349, 'efgh', 107);

CREATE TABLE `resultsmin` (
 `rid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `result` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`rid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1;
INSERT INTO `resultsmin` (`rid`, `cid`, `result`) VALUES
 (1, 12345, 3),
 (2, 12345, 1);

SELECT c.cid, c.club, c.crewno, CONCAT(c.club,c.crewno) crew
 FROM crewsmin c
 LEFT JOIN resultsmin r ON r.cid=c.cid
 GROUP BY c.cid;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the LEFT JOIN if you are not selecting colulmns from `results`?  You need to provide an example more closely mirroring your real query.  The use of GROUP BY in this context makes no sense at all.

Comment: Jim, the real query does uses `results` table data to determine whether a crew has race results and `GROUP BY` makes sure there is only one row in the query results per crew. However, when it comes to triggering the strange behaviour, it makes no difference which columns are joined or selected - as the example shows it's not even necessary to select data from the `results` table.

Comment: Can you post the tables' definitions and the default charset and collation settings of your database?

Comment: @ypercube I was already working on that :) and have added to the question SQL for creating the two tables, with data and the query, so others can (hopefully) replicate and explain the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that MySQL [doesn't always do what you would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479012/how-to-concat-datatypes-like-integersinteger-with-integer-varcharvarchar-wit) when you use CONCAT with numeric values.  You should use CAST on the numeric values:

```
CONCAT(c.club,CAST(c.crewno AS CHAR))
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan but this is not the solution. Even when `CAST` is used the `CONCAT` is still truncated in the manner described. It always truncates to the first digit of `crewno` e.g. I get 'abcd4' instead of 'abcd42' or 'abcd1' instead of 'abcd102'.
The workaround I found (adding a space then triming (or two spaces to get 'abcd102')) suggests there is a completely different problem.

Comment: @trowel I tried your script for reproducing the problem and I get expected results (I don't see the problem).  I am on 5.1.56.

Comment: Thanks for trying @nathan I am on 5.5.8. I just tried on 5.0.27 and the `CONCAT` works as expected so it looks like a version dependant issue (bug?)