# sql - Add 0 after a numeric value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have columns in my sql table. I am wondering how can I add zero after numeric values in my columns. So for example:

I have values e.g 9, 2, 7, 10. I want to add a zero after these numbers. I want them to be 90, 20, 70, 100.

There are some values in the columns that already have 0s after them e.g 70, 20, 100. These ones should retain their values.

How do I go about this?

[image: score table]

Comment: How about multiplying them by ten?

Comment: Actually, I can't fathom why that transformation would be useful.  Why are some needing adjustment and others do not?

Comment: potentially [RPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) will help?

Comment: How do you reconcile that `10` should convert to `100`, but values ending in zero should retain their value?

Comment: So should 100 have another zero, or not?

Comment: 100 should not have another 0

Comment: Friendly tip: when asking a question with an image try to either use a small image in the middle of the text so people see that there is more text or use larger images at the bottom. That will help negate miscommunication to an extent. Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiple the column by ten (not sure what your table name is, edit that query):

```
UPDATE __TABLE__
    SET mt_ca1 = (mt_ca1 * 10),
        mt_ca2 = (mt_ca2 * 10)
WHERE mt_ca1 < 100 OR mt_ca2 < 100;
```

It is not clear if you want to add zeroes after only double-digit numbers or all numbers. MySQL has substring functionality though you'd need to clarify your needs.

Comment: Hi @john , and what about this: "I have values e.g 9, 2, 7, 10. I want to add a zero after these numbers. I want them to be 90, 20, 70, 100." and this: "There are some values in the columns that already have 0s after them e.g 70, 20, 100."

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you get stuck on that last 1% feel free to post a link as a comment and if I'm still awake I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) and [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)

assuming the column type is INT

use CASE to check if the value multiplied to 10 is less than or equal to 100.

```
SELECT 
(CASE
    WHEN (mt_ca1*10) <= 100
    THEN CONVERT(CONCAT(mt_ca1,'0'),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
    ELSE mt_ca1
END) AS mt_ca1
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: I'm not confident that the column type is a text type.

Comment: you can use CONCAT even if column is not text type, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479012/how-to-concat-datatypes-like-integersinteger-with-integer-varcharvarchar-wi

Comment: That's not the point. The point is the *return* type `mt_ca1` may change from `int` to `text`, which may break the clients of the query.

Comment: ahh ok, i got your point, i assumed he/she was using php because it was tagged as phpmyadmin. updated my answer to accomodate if the column type is really int

Comment: Your example has two different column names. Also, the OP asked if there is number 10 then add zero to it and if there is 07,20, 100 then leave it like so. The question from the OP is not vlear but this does not answer that question.

Comment: noted VBoka, modified my answer to accomodate the 10 as well.